# how to do this curl operation in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

What I would like to do is this curl operation in `node.js`.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:12060/repository/schema/fieldType -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '
{
  action: "create",
  fieldType: {
    name: "n$name",
    valueType: { primitive: "STRING" },
    scope: "versioned",
    namespaces: { "my.demo": "n" }
  }
}' -D -
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). request is the de-facto standard way to make HTTP requests from node.js. It's a thin abstraction on top of [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/http.html#http.request)

```
request({
  uri: "localhost:12060/repository/schema/fieldType",
  method: "POST",
  json: {
    action: "create",
    fieldType: {
      name: "n$name",
      valueType: { primitive: "STRING" },
      scope: "versioned",
      namespaces: { "my.demo": "n" }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that as of Node 18, the de-facto standard is [the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 27):

Although there are no specific NodeJS bindings for cURL, we can still issue cURL requests via the command line interface. NodeJS comes with the child_process module which easily allows us to start processes and read their output. Doing so is fairly straight forward. We just need to import the exec method from the child_process module and call it. The first parameter is the command we want to execute and the second is a callback function that accepts error, stdout, stderr.

```
var util = require('util');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var command = 'curl -sL -w "%{http_code} %{time_total}\\n" "http://query7.com" -o /dev/null'

child = exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){

console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

if(error !== null)
{
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
}

});
```

**EDIT** This is also a possible solution: https://github.com/dhruvbird/http-sync

Comment: Why use curl from the command line when you can use `http.request` or node.js directly

Comment: It's just another option. He asked for curl, so I gave him curl :)

Comment: CURL have way more options than http.request (including proxy support)

Comment: In some proxy configurations, it's maddening to try to get node to negotiate the proxy correctly when curl works without trouble.  This is a decent workaround for those who have specific needs.

Comment: See this answer as well, for attaching a listener to the child process if you want to process the returned results from curl.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332721/node-js-spawn-child-process-and-get-terminal-output-instantaneously

Answer (score 3):

take a look at https://github.com/chriso/curlrequest