# Node.js spawn child process and get terminal output live

Tags: node.js, spawn, capture-output

I have a script that outputs 'hi', sleeps for a second, outputs 'hi', sleeps for 1 second, and so on and so forth. Now I thought I would be able to tackle this problem with this model.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
temp    = spawn('PATH TO SCRIPT WITH THE ABOVE BEHAVIOUR');

temp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
```

Now the problem is that the task needs to be finished in order for the output to be displayed. As I am understanding it, this is due to the fact that the newly spawned process takes execution control. Obviously node.js does not support threads so any solutions? My idea was to possibly run two instances, first one for the specific purpose of creating the task and have it pipe the output to process of the second instance, considering this can be achieved.

Comment: If child process is written `python` then do not forget to pass `-u` flag for it to not buffer console output, otherwise it will look like script is not live  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49947671/906265

Comment: Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn instead of anything else. It's just better.

Comment: @foklepoint Did you manage to get it right in the end? I am currently facing a similar problem and none of the answers seem to work for me

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I'm still getting my feet wet with Node.js, but I have a few ideas. first, I believe you need to use `execFile` instead of `spawn`; `execFile` is for when you have the path to a script, whereas `spawn` is for executing a well-known command that Node.js can resolve against your system path.

### 1. [Provide a callback](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback) to process the buffered output:

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile('path/to/script', [ 
    'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 
], function(err, stdout, stderr) { 
    // Node.js will invoke this callback when process terminates.
    console.log(stdout); 
});
```

#### 2. Add a listener to the child process' stdout [stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data) ([9thport.net](http://www.9thport.net/articles/how-to-pipe-a-output-from-child-process-into-a-webpage))

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile('path/to/script', [ 
    'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3' ]); 
// use event hooks to provide a callback to execute when data are available: 
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString()); 
});
```

Further, there appear to be options whereby you can detach the spawned process from Node's controlling terminal, which would allow it to run asynchronously. I haven't tested this yet, but there are examples in the [API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) that go something like this:

```
child = require('child_process').execFile('path/to/script', [ 
    'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 
], { 
    // detachment and ignored stdin are the key here: 
    detached: true, 
    stdio: [ 'ignore', 1, 2 ]
}); 
// and unref() somehow disentangles the child's event loop from the parent's: 
child.unref(); 
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString()); 
});
```

Comment: Bonus points if you can explain how to do this with exec() as I need to execute a shell cmd.

Comment: You can use `child.spawn()` with the `shell` option set to `true`.
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: You can also pipe child.stdout directly to process.stdout with `child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);`

Comment: @DynamicDan

```javascript
let childProcess = exec
(
    './script-to-run --arg1 arg1value',
    ( error, stdout, stderror ) =>
    {
        console.log( '[CALLBACK]: ' + error ); // or stdout or stderror
    }
);

// Same as with spawn:
childProcess.stdout.on
(
    'data',
    ( data ) =>
    {
        console.log( '[LIVE]: ' + data );  // Here's your live data!
    }
);
```

Answer (score 226):

It's much easier now (6 years later)!

Spawn returns a **childObject**, which you can then **listen for events** with. The events are:

- Class: ChildProcess

  - Event: 'error'
  - Event: 'exit'
  - Event: 'close'
  - Event: 'disconnect'
  - Event: 'message'

There are also a bunch of **objects from childObject**, they are:

- Class: ChildProcess

  - child.stdin
  - child.stdout
  - child.stderr
  - child.stdio
  - child.pid
  - child.connected
  - child.kill([signal])
  - child.send(message[, sendHandle][, callback])
  - child.disconnect()

See more information here about childObject: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

## Asynchronous

If you want to run your process in the background while node is still able to continue to execute, use the asynchronous method. You can still choose to perform actions after your process completes, and when the process has any output (for example if you want to send a script's output to the client).

[child_process.spawn(...);](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) (Node v0.1.90)

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn('node ./commands/server.js');

// You can also use a variable to save the output 
// for when the script closes later
var scriptOutput = "";

child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    //Here is where the output goes

    console.log('stdout: ' + data);

    data=data.toString();
    scriptOutput+=data;
});

child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    //Here is where the error output goes

    console.log('stderr: ' + data);

    data=data.toString();
    scriptOutput+=data;
});

child.on('close', function(code) {
    //Here you can get the exit code of the script

    console.log('closing code: ' + code);

    console.log('Full output of script: ',scriptOutput);
});
```

Here's **how you would use a callback + asynchronous method**:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

console.log("Node Version: ", process.version);

run_script("ls", ["-l", "/home"], function(output, exit_code) {
    console.log("Process Finished.");
    console.log('closing code: ' + exit_code);
    console.log('Full output of script: ',output);
});

console.log ("Continuing to do node things while the process runs at the same time...");

// This function will output the lines from the script 
// AS is runs, AND will return the full combined output
// as well as exit code when it's done (using the callback).
function run_script(command, args, callback) {
    console.log("Starting Process.");
    var child = child_process.spawn(command, args);

    var scriptOutput = "";

    child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
    child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + data);

        data=data.toString();
        scriptOutput+=data;
    });

    child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
    child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('stderr: ' + data);

        data=data.toString();
        scriptOutput+=data;
    });

    child.on('close', function(code) {
        callback(scriptOutput,code);
    });
}
```

Using the method above, you can send every line of output from the script to the client (for example using Socket.io to send each line when you receive events on `stdout` or `stderr`).

## Synchronous

If you want node to stop what it's doing and **wait until the script completes**, you can use the synchronous version:

[child_process.spawnSync(...);](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) (Node v0.11.12+)

Issues with this method:

- If the script takes a while to complete, your server will hang for
  that amount of time!
- **The stdout will only be returned once the script
  has finished running**. Because it's synchronous, it cannot continue
  until the current line has finished. Therefore it's unable to capture
  the 'stdout' event until the spawn line has finished.

How to use it:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

var child = child_process.spawnSync("ls", ["-l", "/home"], { encoding : 'utf8' });
console.log("Process finished.");
if(child.error) {
    console.log("ERROR: ",child.error);
}
console.log("stdout: ",child.stdout);
console.log("stderr: ",child.stderr);
console.log("exist code: ",child.status);
```

Comment: +1, this should be chosen as the right answer now. Just a note, the data variable in the callback comes in as Buffer object. You can use ```child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8')``` if you want utf8 strings coming in.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need the information from `stdout` asynchronously, that is, while the remaining program continues, if the process continues.

Comment: Hey @ChristianHujer ! I updated my answer to include both async and sync :D

Comment: if you have a script that is: `console.log("Output 1"); console.error("Boom"); console.log("Output 2");` and I'm doing `spawnAsync('node ./script.js')` ... how do you preserve the order of the output? My output always seems to come out in the incorrect order.

Comment: FYI, it's even easier if you use `pipe` or `pipeline` or pass in the appropriate options to `spawn`.

Comment: If you're using spawnSync and want the values to come back as a string instead of a buffer you'll want to feed in { encoding: 'utf-8' } as part of the options (3rd param).

Comment: The asynchronous `child_process`  logging works when there is only one child process involved.
But when there are multiple child processes running at the same, console.log from the parent process start randomly truncating data.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this! great answer much better than most so posts! Still can't seem to get this to work correctly to pipe from a parent to a spawned child; but at least i partially solved it. Everyone likes to remind me that js isn't meant to do this etc etc. well thanks for stating the obvious i say!. This is why i was thrilled to find your detailed answer.

Comment: Using `process.stdout.write(data);` instead of `console.log` in the async example leads to better outputs, like being able to overwrite the same line with a progress bar instead of creating a newline every time

Comment: On windows at least, the stdout pipe needs to be flushed before node.js will generate an on('data') event. So, when I ran a c++ program which I created that had `std::cout << "Hi\n";`, this would appear in an interactive console, but was not received in node.js. However, the code `std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl;` did trigger a on('data') event because the endl triggers a flush. I think you can also manually call fflush().

Answer (score 60):

Here is the cleanest approach I've found:

```
require("child_process").spawn('bash', ['./script.sh'], {
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  detached: true,
  stdio: "inherit"
});
```

Comment: What is it doing, exactly? Why does it work? Why is this the cleaner approach?

Comment: @raisinrising It is setting the process to inherit the stdio handles (including stdout). It is cleaner because there is only one function invocation (sorry for the partial comment that I deleted, a pack of index cards was dropped on my keyboard while I was away)

Comment: Simple and worked for me. I didnt need the detached option and my process was actually attached 

Comment: Agreed, this is clean, simple, and allows processes to output directly to console (i.e. if there's a fancy spinning character or whatever).

Comment: SHOULD BE ACCEPTED ANSWER +1

Answer (score 19):

I had a little trouble getting logging output from the "npm install" command when I spawned npm in a child process. The realtime logging of dependencies did not show in the parent console.

The simplest way to do what the original poster wants seems to be this (spawn npm on windows and log everything to parent console):

```
var args = ['install'];

var options = {
    stdio: 'inherit' //feed all child process logging into parent process
};

var childProcess = spawn('npm.cmd', args, options);
childProcess.on('close', function(code) {
    process.stdout.write('"npm install" finished with code ' + code + '\n');
});
```

Answer (score 9):

**PHP-like passthru**

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

export default async function passthru(exe, args, options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const env = Object.create(process.env);
        const child = spawn(exe, args, {
            ...options,
            env: {
                ...env,
                ...options.env,
            },
        });
        child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
        child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
        child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data));
        child.stderr.on('data', data => console.log(data));
        child.on('error', error => reject(error));
        child.on('close', exitCode => {
            console.log('Exit code:', exitCode);
            resolve(exitCode);
        });
    });
}
```

**Usage**

```
const exitCode = await passthru('ls', ['-al'], { cwd: '/var/www/html' })
```

Answer (score 4):

child:

```
setInterval(function() {
    process.stdout.write("hi");
}, 1000); // or however else you want to run a timer
```

parent:

```
require('child_process').fork('./childfile.js');
// fork'd children use the parent's stdio
```

Answer (score 4):

I found myself requiring this functionality often enough that I packaged it into a library called [std-pour](https://www.npmjs.com/package/std-pour).  It should let you execute a command and view the output in real time. To install simply:

```
npm install std-pour
```

Then it's simple enough to execute a command and see the output in realtime:

```
const { pour } = require('std-pour');
pour('ping', ['8.8.8.8', '-c', '4']).then(code => console.log(`Error Code: ${code}`));
```

It's promised based so you can chain multiple commands. It's even function signature-compatible with [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) so it should be a drop in replacement anywhere you're using it.

Comment: @KodieGrantham glad it's working for you! Y'all seem like you're doing some cool work so I hope it keeps you running.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a sample for `exec` as I too had needed live feedback and wasn't getting any until after the script finished. `exec` *does* return an **EventEmitter**, contrary to the many claims that only `spawn` works in such a way.

This supplements the comment I made to the accepted answer more thoroughly.

The interface for exec is similar to spawn:

```js
// INCLUDES
import * as childProcess from 'child_process'; // ES6 Syntax
    
    
// DEFINES
let exec = childProcess.exec; // Use 'var' for more proper 
                              // semantics, or 'const' it all
                              // if that's your thing; though 'let' is 
                              // true-to-scope;

// Return an EventEmitter to work with, though
// you can also chain stdout too: 
// (i.e. exec( ... ).stdout.on( ... ); )
let childProcess = exec
(
    './binary command -- --argument argumentValue',
    ( error, stdout, stderr ) =>
    {    // When the process completes:
        if( error )
        {   
            console.log( `${error.name}: ${error.message}` );
            console.log( `[STACK] ${error.stack}` );
        }
            
        console.log( stdout );
        console.log( stderr );
        callback();                // Gulp stuff
    }
);
```

Now its as simple as registering an event handler for `stdout`:

```js
childProcess.stdout.on( 'data', data => console.log( data ) );
```

And for `stderr`:

```js
childProcess.stderr.on( 'data', data => console.log( `[ERROR]: ${data}` ) );
```

You can also `pipe` stdout to the main process' stdout:

```js
childProcess.stdout.pipe( process.stdout );
```

Not too bad at all - HTH

Answer (score 1):

I was interested into running a script that gets the input and outputs from my terminal, and that will close my process once the child script finishes.

```js
import { spawn } from 'node:child_process'
import process from 'node:process'

const script = spawn('path/to/script', { stdio: 'inherit' })
script.on('close', process.exit)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Read subprocess stdout line-by-line with `readline`**

Reading line by line live is a common use case since many CLI utilities produce line-oriented output.

Sample program:

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const childProcess = require('child_process')
const readline = require('readline')

const p = childProcess.spawn('./count.js', ['2'])
;(async function() {
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: p.stdout })
for await (const line of rl) {
  console.log('read: ' + line)
}
})()
```

Test helper:

count.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
(async function() {
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
let i = 0
let max
if (process.argv.length > 2) {
  max = parseInt(process.argv[2])
}
while (true) {
  console.log(i)
  if (i === max) break
  await sleep(1000)
  i++
}
})()
```

Output of `./main.js`:

```
read: 0
read: 1
read: 2
```

and each line appears one second after the previous one. Therefore we understand that this is reading lines immediately as soon as they become available as desired, and not waiting until the subprocess terminates to read everything at once.

A more dedicated question for this specific case is present at: [Parse output of spawned node.js child process line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781214/parse-output-of-spawned-node-js-child-process-line-by-line)

Tested on Node.js v16.14.2, Ubuntu 23.04.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a situation where none of the above worked when I was spawning a Python 3 script. I would get data from stdout, but only once the child terminated.

As it turns out, Python buffers stdout by default. It's possible to disable stdout buffering by including `-u` as a command line parameter to python3.