# How do I use npm forever-monitor to log to stdout

Tags: node.js, forever-monitor

I have a simple nodejs docker service. I'm watching stdout in development and logging to AWS cloudwatch in production.

I've just added forever-monitor, but that breaks my logging. So I've started catching stdout on the child process,

```
const forever = require('forever-monitor');

const child = new (forever.Monitor)('server.js', {
  max: 3,
  silent: true,
  args: []
});

child.on('stdout', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

but that just gives me byte code out -

```
[nodemon] starting `node forever.js`
<Buffer 63 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 65 64 20 74 6f 20 6c 69 76 65 20 64 62 0a>
```

How do I get my `console.log` statements back into std-out?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `data` is a stream (see [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data)).

I've updated my code to -

```
child.on('stdout', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

And now it's working as expected. (I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332721/node-js-spawn-child-process-and-get-terminal-output-live) useful).