# Receiving contiinuous output from python spawn child process not working

Tags: python, node.js, stdout, child-process, spawn

I am attempting to stream output from a weighing scale that is written in python. This program (scale.py) runs continuously and prints the raw value every half second.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys

from hx711 import HX711

def cleanAndExit():
    print "Cleaning..."
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print "Bye!"
    sys.exit()

hx = HX711(5, 6)

hx.set_reading_format("LSB", "MSB")

hx.reset()
hx.tare()

while True:
    try:
        val = hx.get_weight(5)
        print val

        hx.power_down()
        hx.power_up()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        cleanAndExit()
```

I am trying to get each raw data point in a separate NodeJs program (index.js located in the same folder) that is printed by `print val`.  Here is my node program.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var py = spawn('python', ['scale.py']);

py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  console.log("Data: " + data);
});

py.stderr.on('data', function(data){
  console.log("Error: " + data);
});
```

When I run `sudo node index.js` there is no output and the program waits into perpetuity.

My thought process is that `print val` should put output into stdout stream and this should fire the `data` event in the node program.  But nothing is happening.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, all C programs (CPython included as it is written in C) that use libc will automatically buffer console output when it is connected to a pipe.

One solution is to flush the output buffer every time you need:

```
print val
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Another solution is to invoke python with the `-u` flag which forces it to be unbuffered:

```
var py = spawn('python', ['-u', 'scale.py']);
```

Comment: AWESOME!  I was so close yet so far.  Thank you for explaining the buffer, I had no idea that was the behavior.  FYI, The first solution worked out better for me as the second was producing a blank write after each data point.  Thanks!

Comment: that's a really great answer for what I was looking for about 3 hours or so! I created a standalone using pyinstaller, but I had to use `sys.stdout.flush()` for it to work, so really thank you! though It would be nice of you if you know a way so that the pyinstaller would use the `-u` argument by default (seems the argument not working with it)

Comment: I can't tell you how happppy I am, I have been struggling with this for days, and finally finalllllllly I found this answer, Thanks a lot, works like charm!!!