# Using node app inside an express js server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an Express js server endpoint with the following directory structure:

- app.js
- node_modules
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- mrz-detection

The mrz-detection directory, contains a node app which I would normally call from the command line like this `node run/getMrz.js --file passport.jpg`

My app.js looks like this

```
const { getMrz } = require('./mrz-detection');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb', extended: true}));
var passportsArr = [];


app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var passport = req.body;
    let buff = new Buffer(passport.data, 'base64');
    fs.writeFileSync('passport.png', buff);
    // send passport photo to mrz-detection app here
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Mrz detection app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

I need to call the mrz-detection app from my post route in the app.js

How would I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js spawn child process and get terminal output live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332721/node-js-spawn-child-process-and-get-terminal-output-live)

Comment: mrz-detection is a package :/ implement it in the post method, the code in `run` folder is just wrapping it for cli

Comment: Okay thanks @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of to do this:

1. [Call the other program command-line-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332721/node-js-spawn-child-process-and-get-terminal-output-live) as explained by a commentor
2. Refactor your code so that you can simply import a function from your other file and use it. I would recommend this more because it allows for complex parameters to potentially be passed without having to serialize and deserialize them in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You could you start the app as a child process:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

There are a few different 'child_process' functions for spawning child processes

execFile
spawn
fork

With fork, sending messages between parent and child works automatically

```
const fork = require('child_process').fork;
const child = fork('/path/to/app.js', ['optional', 'arguments']);

// message from child
child.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message from child ' + msg);
}

// send message to child
child.send({hi:'hi from parent'});
```